# Exportar Informe Access a Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

disculpen tengo un informe en access con un formato en las cabeceras de las columnas,y campos de hiperniculos,al exportar a excel me lo exporta sin formato, como puedo hacer la exportacion respetando el formato que tengo. Gracias

Comment: El asistente de exportación a Excel debería darte la opción de marcar una casilla que dice "Exportar datos con formato y diseño". ¿No te sirve esa opción?

Comment: Bienvenido. Falta incluir una breve descripción de lo buscado/investigado así como de lo que has intentado. Referencia [ask].

Answer (score 0):

De Accsess a Excel se exporta usando el Asistente de Exportación.
Copiando lo que indica la página oficial de Office (https://support.office.com/es-es/article/exportar-datos-a-excel-64e974e6-ae43-4301-a53e-20463655b1a9):

1. Si el libro de destino de Excel está abierto, ciérrelo antes de continuar.
2. En el panel de navegación de la base de datos de origen, seleccione el objeto que desea exportar (o seleccione los registros deseados en la vista hoja de datos)
   En la pestaña Datos externos, en el grupo Exportar, haga clic en Excel.
3. En el cuadro de diálogo Exportar a una hoja de cálculo de Excel, compruebe el nombre de archivo propuesto para el libro de Excel (Access usa el nombre del objeto de origen). Si lo desea, puede modificar el nombre de archivo.
4. En el cuadro Formato de archivo, seleccione el formato de archivo que desee.

Si está exportando una tabla o consulta y desea exportar datos con formato, seleccione Exportar datos con formato y diseño.

Si todavía quedan dudas este link quizás te las resuelva https://support.office.com/es-es/article/exportar-datos-a-excel-64e974e6-ae43-4301-a53e-20463655b1a9?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES#__prepare_for_the